# Have "individual" logging instead of logging everything to "journalctl" on CentOS 7

Tags: centos-7, syslog

On my CentOS 7 system, no output are written to the well known log files and I'm forced to use `journalctl` to view anything that happening.

For example, there is no data in `/var/log/messages`, nor `/var/log/syslog`, nor `/var/log/mail`

Everything instead is being logged to the "journal". So to see what's happening, I have to do:

`journalctl -f` (follow)

I don't want everything logged to a single place, I would prefer normal logging.

Is there a way to switch off this journal logging?

Comment: The logging can be configured for a systemd unit by creating a file in `/etc/systemd/system`. Or pipe the output of `journalctl` to `grep` and filter it out. This may also help https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401676.

Answer (score 0):

If you install and enable rsyslog, you will enable traditional logging to /var/log/messages, etc.